# a program that reads in a variable-length array from a file using loops

Tags: c

```
void printArray(char * array, FILE * fp1, int MAX_CHAR)
{ 
 int i; /* initializing i */
 FILE *fp1
 fp1 = fopen("Array.txt","r+");      /* open the file in append mode */
 for (i=0; i<MAX_CHAR; i++)           /* using for loop */
      fprintf(fp1,"%c",*(array+i)); /* writing the array */ 
 fclose(fp1);                       /* close the file pointer */ 

 return 0; 
}
```

im new to C can someone let me know if i did this correctly

Comment: No one here can tell you whether or not this is working any better than you can tell yourself by compiling and running it.

Comment: There's no reading there, just writing. Is there another part of the program you want us to look at?

Comment: You mean other than the fact that you never actually `read()` the file... either your title or your code is completely wrong.

Comment: What are you going to read the array in? I don't suppose another C program because you would then just pass it as argument..and btw google search for reshaping arrays...will save you a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got some errors in this function. Here's what I suggest you :

```
void printArray(char *array, const int MAX_CHAR)
{ 
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("Array.txt", "a");      /* open the file in append mode */
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_CHAR; i++)           /* using for loop */
       fprintf(fp1,"%c",*(array+i)); /* writing the array */ 
    fclose(fp1);                       /* close the file pointer */ 
}
```

About the modes when you open file : [fopen function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/). If you really want to pass `fp1` as input parameter, then do this :

```
void printArray(char *array, FILE *fp1, const int MAX_CHAR)
{ 
    fp1 = fopen("Array.txt", "a");      /* open the file in append mode */
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_CHAR; i++)           /* using for loop */
       fprintf(fp1,"%c",*(array+i)); /* writing the array */ 
    fclose(fp1);                       /* close the file pointer */ 
}
```

Finally, I would suggest you to take a look at the [fwrite function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).